# I am scraping a data using beautifulsoup but i'm not get all data

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

there is something wrong for extract all data using python scraping

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/" 
req_data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req_data.text, 'html.parser') 
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'main_table_countries_today'}) 
for row in table.findAll('tr', attrs = {'class':['odd','even','total_row']}): 
    print(row.text)
```

Comment: only get total table row and i need all raw (text data)

Comment: what do you mean by raw data? can you provide in the question what you get? and what you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests , csv

def SaveAsCsv(list_of_rows):
    try:
        print('\nSaving CSV Result')
        with open('output.csv', 'a',  newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerow(list_of_rows)
            print("rsults saved successully")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Please make sure output.csv is closed \n")

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/" 
req_data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req_data.text, 'html.parser') 
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'main_table_countries_today'})

header = [col_name.text.rstrip('\n').strip() for col_name in table.select('thead th')]
SaveAsCsv(header)


for row in table.select('tbody tr'):
    tds = [td.get_text().rstrip('\n').strip() for td in  row.select('td')]
    SaveAsCsv(tds)
    # print(row.text.rstrip('\n').strip())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


r = requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
df = pd.read_html(r.content)

print(df)
```